# python generator argument are not initialized as default value

Tags: python, arguments, generator, default-value

Maybe this is a very easy question to someone, I can't understand what this happened.

I try to solve problems using python **generator**. 
However, sometime generator seems not to work that I expected.

The code below is the very simple python generator. 
It takes integer `n` and set `visited` as its arguments. 
`visited` should be initialized `set()` when the function is called.

```py
def simple_gen(n, visited=set()): 
    for i in range(0, n):
        if i not in visited:
            yield i
            visited.update([i])

a = simple_gen(10)
b = simple_gen(10)
print(f"a: {list(a)}")
print(f"b: {list(b)}")
```

But, when the code is executed, the output is like below. 
generator `a` generator value like that I expected, but `b` doesn't. `b` doesn't generator any value, it is just empty value.

arguement `visited` always initialized to empty set as default value. 
but it doesn't look like initializing.

```
a: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
b: []
```

I don't understand why this happened. 
Are there anyone know this, please let me know.

I always thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python's default parameters are stored *in the function object*. This means they're only created once when the function is defined, they are not initialised every time the function is called.

As a result, if you modify a mutable parameter, that modification *will remain between calls*.

And that's exactly what you're doing here: you have a mutable default parameter, you add stuff to it on the first call, and on the second call `visited` starts as `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}`. That's why you don't normally use mutable default parameters in Python, it's very error prone and somewhat tricky to debug.

Create your `visited` as a normal local variable, I don't see any reason why it'd even be a parameter.

Comment: Thank for your help. "pythons' default parameter are stored in the function object" is the correct thing I want to know. I really appreciated your help.

Comment: Incidentally, although the way the mapping works is a bit odd, they're stored in `func.__defaults__` and `func.__kwdefaults__` (as the name indicates, the latter is for keyword-only parameters).